# MVC4 Razr throws error on AngularJS email regex pattern

Tags: regex, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Within my MVC4 view, I'm using AngularJS to validate my form fields. Everything works great except for the email validation. I'm using AngularJS v1.2.26 within MVC4 project. Here's the regex pattern I'm using.`ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"`. My problem is I receive a runtime error in browser when Razr hits the '@' symbol in the regex pattern and the page blows up. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` is a special symbol in Razor syntax. To use it on the page just use a double `@@` like this:

```
ng-pattern="/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"
```

Comment: I added another '@' to the regex and it doesn't work. Here's my altered regex 'ng-pattern="/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/"' and the error I receive at runtime 'Parser Error Message: "\" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.'. I've removed '\' from my regex and I still receive the same error.

Comment: Then you need to give me some more context of your view as I can put that in my Razor and it works fine.

Comment: Or, can you try using, instead of `@`, use `&#64;`

Comment: Double '@' does not work in Razor within an attribute value. Davids suggestion of using the HTML character entity '&#64;' does however.

Comment: @DavidG You got an upvote for the correct answer too ;) Never given both to the same person on one answer before - we need a new badge!

Comment: @CountZero Or a hat! Though I'm confused how I got both in this :)

Comment: Your comment on using '&#64;' was the key :) Not pretty but Razor gets confused by '@@' in attribute="value@@". You definetly earned a christmas hat on this one :)